# Detect Hover over Background Image

Tags: css, hover

I have an input text.
I added a background image which is smaller than the input element.
I want to change the image when I hover over the image only.

this is my css:

```
#inputBox2{
    top:45%;
    background-image:url(".\\Images\\arrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 14% 100%;
    background-position: right;
}
```

**Edit:** I am trying to do this: [image]

When I hover over the arrow I want it to change color and when i click on it it should submit

Comment: :hover I believe works on the whole input text. I want to change it only when I hover over the background image.

Comment: You can't really. Use a separate element, not a background image.

Comment: can I add a separate element to the input using javascript?

Comment: explain better what you are trying to achive, there is another way to do it

Comment: can't you just use a styled submit button?

Comment: are you saying it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use css `:hover` for a part of an element. So basically, no, you can't do what you're trying to do. At least not the way you want to do it.

You can achieve the same effect, however, by using a styled `submit` button. Why would you want to submit a form when the user clicks an image in the background of an input textbox anyway? That's semantically just wrong.

Use a `<label>` tag for the 'Password' label, an `<input type="password"/>` tag for the password input, and use an `<input type="submit"/>` tag for the submit button. You can then style the submit button using CSS to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate inline element (or floated block element) that has a background image set to the arrow. Then you could use :hover on that element.

(Or this element could simply be an `<image>` element, with a hover property.)

Comment: can I add this image element using javascript? Can you give me a quick example on how to do it? Thank you

Comment: @VladOtrocol: You can pretty much add any element using javascript.