# How to fire click event on the css attribute(background)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is that I want to fire a click event on a css attribute I am dynamically creating a table and inside that table there are cells and there are 3 partition on each cell. All this is created dynamically.

Inside each partition there is an image, so I want to fire click event only on that image of those partitions. Below is my code.

```
function createInnerDiv(day, period)
{
    var divSub      =   document.createElement('div');
    var divT        =   document.createElement('div');
   var divTopics    =   document.createElement('div');

    divSub.id       =   "Sub" + day + "" + period;
    divT.id         =   "T" + day + "" + period;
    divTopics.id    =   "Topics" + day + "" + period;

    divSub.addEventListener('click',function(){
        teacherTT       =   divT.innerHTML;
    });

    divT.addEventListener('click',function(){
        teacherTT = $(this).html();
    });

    divTopics.addEventListener('click',function(){
        teacherTT=divT.innerHTML;
    });

    divx.appendChild(divSub);
    divx.appendChild(divT);
    divx.appendChild(divTopics);
}
```

CSS for it:

```
.class
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid antiquewhite;
    background: url("../images/cross-bright.png") no-repeat scroll 98% center;
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated...thanku...

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow us to help you more efficiently (consider compiling your codes in a snippet or jsfiddle)

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314004/detect-hover-over-background-image . It's not precisely the same but the general  idea of what the OP is trying to do is similar. I don't think you can do what you're asking - events can only be attached to DOM elements, not to attributes

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle for that..

Comment: @ADyson i know that i can only fire events on DOM elements..but i think that this can be acheive with javacsript...have to tweak it though

Comment: @AnkitRauthan what is 'teacherTT'? is it a variable? you haven't declared it as such

Comment: @AnkitRauthan but since your image doesn't exist as a dom element (it's just shown due to the CSS attribute) then you can't handle a click event for it. There's no way to detect that the user has interacted with it. If the image covers the whole of the div, you can just handle the click of the div.

Comment: @Rachel Gallen yes teacherTT is a global variable...whose value is given below

Comment: @AnkitRauthan do you want to change the image onclick? if so you can update the css via jquery

Comment: @RachelGallen the image which is given there is a cross image...so i want to remove that partition when click on image

Comment: @AnkitRauthan so you just want to remove the image on click? or the full div? which div are you adding the image to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582192/how-to-bind-click-event-on-image-added-using-css-background-image-property-in... see this for reference... this is exactly what i want

Comment: @RachelGallen i want to remove that partition div...

Comment: @AnkitRauthan i don't understand the reference - there is nothing removed in the fiddle

Comment: @RachelGallen ok let me clear the stuff for you... there is a table which is created dynamically... there is a div which is also created dynamically which is divx...and then there are three divs within it which are also dynamically created i.e. divSub,divT and divTopics...and the image are given to those three divs

Comment: exactly...all i want is...i want to fire an event on image click or any other alternative whatever works

Comment: @ADyson see the link that i've sent for example...can't we just fix the position of click event in the div with the help of javascript...

Comment: @AnkitRauthan well that example you linked to seems to do what you want. what's the issue with it?

Comment: @AnkitRauthan Alternatively, since you're doing this on a div not an input, why not have a button with your image as the background? Then you can control exactly where it is within the div, control its size, and have a separate click event to handle closing the containing div. Just like it was a modal popup or something. Seems simpler than messing about with mouse positions

Comment: @ADyson well first of all thanks for helping me with this...and the think is that i'am a newbie...and i doesn't able to understand that code,nor its working...i couldn't implement it and nor iam familiar with the events its using

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what div you need to add a class in the click event, but this is how you can do this.

```
divTopics.addEventListener('click',function(){
    teacherTT=divT.innerHTML;
    $(divTopics).addClass('class');
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/